# How do I just retrieve one column from Azure database as opposed to select *

Tags: ios, objective-c, azure

I am currently accessing an azure mobile server database that has the columns `id` and `text`. How do I just select the `text` column as opposed to selecting all the columns.

```
- (IBAction)nextJokeButton:(id)sender
{
MSClient *client = [(AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] client];
MSTable *itemTable = [client tableWithName:@"mytable"];
[itemTable readWithCompletion:^(NSArray *items, NSInteger totalCount, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    } else {
        NSString *str1 = items[3];
        NSLog(@"%@", str1);
    }
}];
}
```

Currently logs

```
2014-05-06 11:32:11.349 project[9521:a0b] {
id = "F6098E3B-A7ED-4AAA-BA8F-11A879551057";
text = "United Kingdom";
}
```

I just need the string to equal the text part.
Thanks!
p.s this is my first post to stackoverflow, if I have not added enough detail please ask for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
NSString *str1 = [items[3] objectForKey:@"text"];
NSLog(@"%@", str1);
```